# How to splice an array that is in a hash of arrays?

Tags: perl

I am populating a data structure like so:-

```
push @{$AvailTrackLocsTop{$VLayerName}}, $CurrentTrackLoc;
```

Where $VLayerName is a string like m1, m2, m3, etc., and $CurrentTrackLoc is simply a decimal number. If I use Data::Dumper to print the contents of the hash after it is fully populated, it reveals what I expect, e.g.:-

```
$VAR1 = {
      'm11' => [
                 '0.228',
                 '0.316',
                 '0.402',
                 '0.576',
                 '0.750',
                 '569.458',
                 '569.544',
                 '569.718',
                 '569.892'
               ]
    };
```

Now I need to effectively splice the stored list of decimal numbers. I can delete entries like so:-

```
for (my $i = $c; $i <= $endc; $i++) {
    delete $AvailTrackLocsTop{$VLayerName}->[$i];
}
```

The result is, as expected, a bunch of "undef" entries where numbers used to exist, e.g.:-

```
$VAR1 = {
      'm11' => [
                 undef,
                 undef,
                 undef,
                 undef,
                 '0.750',
                 '569.458',
                 '569.544',
                 '569.718',
                 '569.892'
               ]
    };
```

But how can I purge the undef entries so that I see something like this instead?

```
$VAR1 = {
      'm11' => [
                 '0.750',
                 '569.458',
                 '569.544',
                 '569.718',
                 '569.892'
               ]
    };
```

It is important to note that the deletions can be anywhere in the array, e.g. like index 33 and 99 of 100. It is easy to splice arrays outside the context of a hash structure, but I am struggling to manipulate the array when it is embedded inside a large hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I want to note from the [delete](https://perldoc.pl/functions/delete) documentation:

```
WARNING: Calling delete on array values is strongly discouraged. The notion of deleting or checking the existence of Perl array elements is not conceptually coherent, and can lead to surprising behavior.
```

The correct way to set an array element to undef is with the [undef](https://perldoc.pl/functions/undef) function (or just assigning undef to it).

To instead remove the elements, you can use the [splice](https://perldoc.pl/functions/splice) function, it works the same way on nested arrayrefs as on a normal array, you just need to dereference it like you did for `push`.

```
splice @{$AvailTrackLocsTop{$VLayerName}}, $c, $endc - $c + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Grinnz--that is exactly what I needed. I did not realize that nested array refs could be manipulated so cleanly. And thanks, too, for the heads-up regarding the delete operation...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest given where you're at is to rebuild the arrays without the undefs:

```
$_ = [ grep defined, @$_ ] for values %AvailTrackLocsTop;
```

Alternatively, instead of a hash of arrays, you could have a hash of hashes, and then deleting will cause them to disappear without simply turning to undef. You'll just lose the order, if that matters.